# How I can check error from try/catch block in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, try-catch, supertest

How I can test my try / catch block in Jest if there is an error I'm sure that catch will handle? For example I want to test this code for reading a token from a separate file. I want to test my catch but the problem is that I don't know how to create a situation in Jest to make an error to handle in Jest.

```
const readToken = async () => {
try{
    const readFile = await fs.readFile('./apiData.json');
    const data = JSON.parse(readFile);
    
    return data.token;
    
}catch(err){
    throw err;
}
}
```

And this is my Jest code but is not working correct I think because in coverage show me that line with catch(err) is uncovered.

```
        it('should return catch error',async (done) => {
        try{
          
           await readToken()
            done()
        }catch(e){
          done(e);
        }
      })
```

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror? And your catch is totally pointless.

Comment: `}catch(err){    throw err; }` is no-op and shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: so can you tell me more how i should handle error in this function ?

Comment: The way you need it. Nobody but you can decide that. If you need it to throw an error as is like it currently does, remove try..catch.

Comment: So you wanna say that in this function is not necessary write try and catch ? thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: It's necessary if you need to do something with an error besides throwing it, e.g. logging it, transforming it, *not* throwing it. `try { throwErr() } catch (err) { throw err }` is the same as `throwErr()` alone.

Comment: So you think if I will write catch(err){ console.error(err) } its correct ? I study already 1 year JS and i still have problem with this errors I cant understand when we should use try/catch if is good to use it in every function or not. Maybe you know some good article about this ?

Comment: It's correct but may be bad habit for error handling at the large scale. The only way a caller may be aware that `readToken` failed is that it returns `undefined`, and this is impossible if a function can return `undefined` when working normalky. If you're unsure what you do, throw an error and leave error handing to a caller. Also, consider using `@`, otherwise users don't receive notification and leave your comments unanswered.

Comment: @EstusFlask ok thank you. so i have one more question if i will use catch (err) { console.error(err) } how i can test this in Jest like call this function but this function will run without any error so in my test will passing and it will not catch error. I need to run this function with some error from Jest so how I can do that ? or I'm wrong.

Comment: Mock a function that is expected to throw an error with Jest, `jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFile').mockRejectedValue(new Error(whatever))`. Spy on expected side effect, `jest.spyOn(console, 'error')`. Assert that both spies were called.

Comment: @EstusFlask ok I will try to do it. I just start working with testing its my fourth day. Thank you so much. I would like to ask you if is possible in some way have to contact with you for future if I will have some questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221386/discussion-between-votech-and-estus-flask).

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. Consider pinging me with `@` in a question where I participated like this one. I'm checking new Jest questions so will likely check yours in case you have one.

Comment: @EstusFlask Hey thank you for hint about @ heheh you are so helpful. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mock `fs.readFile` to get it to throw an error for you:

```
  it('should handle a readFile error', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFile')
     .mockImplementation(async () => { throw new Error('Some error'); });
    await expect(readToken()).rejects.toThrowError();
    fs.readFile.mockRestore()
  });
```

You could do the same with JSON.parse:

```
  it('should handle a JSON.parse error', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(JSON, 'parse')
     .mockImplementation(() => { throw new Error('Some error'); });
    await expect(readToken()).rejects.toThrowError();
    JSON.parse.mockRestore()
  });
```

Both of those tests would get the code in the catch block to run and bump up your test coverage. If you want to log the error to the console instead of throwing it again in the catch block, you can test for it like this:

```
  it('should handle a readFile error', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFile')
     .mockImplementation(() => { throw new Error('Some error'); });
    jest.spyOn(console, 'error')
     .mockImplementation();
    await readToken();
    expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I would like to ask you if I can use also jest.spyOn for call a async function from function for example 

const function = async () => {
try{
 await somefunction()
}catch(err){
console.error(err);
}
}

Comment: `jest.spyOn` can be used to track calls to an existing method and also mock its implementation or return value if necessary. The documentation is pretty good and detailed: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: In your example, the way you mock `somefunction` depends on where it is being declared; I'd have to see more code.

Comment: Hmm for example if I have this function:

const refreshToken = async (token) => {
    try{
        const decodeToken =  jwt.decode(token, {complete: true})
        const { payload } = decodeToken;

        if (Date.now() >= payload.exp * 1000) {

            await loginApi();
            return await readToken();

        } else {

            return token;
        }
    }catch(err){
            console.error(err);
     }        
   
}

how i can check if async function loginApi() is working correct ? 
Thank you for your time and answer.

Comment: What would you like to mock in that case?

Comment: I think await loginApi() because its show me in coverage that this line with await loginApi() is uncoverage so its mean that is not tested ? maybe im wrong but i just practice Jest fourth days :)

Comment: for the mockImplementation I forgot to add async keyword in front of the function throwing the error. Once I added that, it worked fine. Many thanks daniloxxv.